# Magnus Effect influencing Hurricane Balls motion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics

In the motion of a hurricane ball, two sphere are glued or welded to each other and can be spun at very high RPM's, while one ball is rotating on a surface, the other ball is inclined to the surface at a certain degree, spinning along its horizontal axis in the air. What I would like to clarify is the ball that is spinning in the air, would the Magnus force be significant enough to limit the angle of inclination of the ball, as my understanding is the ball spinning in the air is going through topspin in the rotational motion of the Hurricane Balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, what a great question!

Ok, well given that the critical RPM for these tends to be around 10 RPM, and that they are on the order of a few centimeters total, it would see the difference in velocity of the air flow would be tiny. I suspect the resulting force would be too small to notice unless they were going some ungodly speed.

Comment: I see so the critical RPM which is 10 would be too little to actually see a difference in velocity of air flow, thus the magnus effect would not be significant at all, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Compared to the density of the objects, yes. If they were made out of aerogel instead of steel... maybe.